# Multidimensional arrays From C to Swift

Tags: multidimensional-array, swift

In C I have the following multidimensional array:

```
unsigned wins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

To access the elements I use the following code:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)     {
    unsigned *positions;
    positions = wins[i];

    unsigned pos0 = positions[0];
    unsigned pos1 = positions[1];
    unsigned pos2 = positions[2];

    if(arrayPassedIn[pos0] != 0 && arrayPassedIn[pos0] == arrayPassedIn[pos1] && arrayPassedIn[pos0] == arrayPassedIn[pos2])
    {
         // Do Something Here
    }
```

I know in swift I can do something like:

```
var array = Array<Array<Int>>()
```

But I'm not sure if this produces the same result for accessing the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a multi-dimentsional array in a pretty similar manner to your C code:

```
var wins = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
```

The Swift code to use it the same way as your C code is also pretty similar; the main difference is using a for-in loop instead of the standard `for` loop (although you could do that too).

```
for positions in wins {
    var pos0 = positions[0]
    var pos1 = positions[1]
    var pos2 = positions[2]

    if(arrayPassedIn[pos0] != 0 && arrayPassedIn[pos0] == arrayPassedIn[pos1] && arrayPassedIn[pos0] == arrayPassedIn[pos2])
    {
        // Do Something Here
    }
}
```

Do note that, even though there are similarities, Arrays in Swift are **not** like arrays in C. For instance, when you're looping over `wins`, you're actually creating copies of the `positions` arrays (the actual memory copy only happens if you write to the array, so there's not really a performance penalty). If you then set, say, `positions[0]` to a different value, that value would **not** be updated in `wins` like it would if this were C.

Comment: Thanks for details.  I was just creating another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291862/swift-iterating-over-an-array-and-updating-value-error-lvalue-t5-is-not-i

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked in obj-C, but in swift I think the equivalent is:

```
let array: [(Int, Int, Int)] = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6)]
println(array[2].0) //6
```

Comment: Technically that's an Array of [Tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_481), not a multi-dimensional array. It might work fine depending on how it needs to be used though.