# Iterating over an array and updating value. error: '@lvalue $T5' is not identical to 'Int'

Tags: swift

I have the following syntax in `Swift`:

```
func basicFunction(anArray:[Int], aValue:Int) -> Int {
    for (var i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if anArray[i] == 0
        {
            anArray[i] = aValue  //I get an error in XCode
        }
    }
    return 1
}
```

I get the following `Xcode error`: `'@lvalue $T5`' is not identical to '`Int`'

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show us the declaration of `spaces`.

Comment: sorry.  adjust the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Array optional Type and subscripting (Beta 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710208/swift-array-optional-type-and-subscripting-beta-3)

Comment: @MartinR you are right.  Also works with Swift 1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function arguments are immutable by default, and the Swift compiler gives terrible error messages.

Anyway, because `anArray` is immutable, you cannot modify it.  That's why you get an error message.   Declare it `inout`:

```
func basicFunction(inout anArray:[Int], aValue:Int) -> Int {
    for (var i = 0; i<5; ++i) {
        if anArray[i] == 0 {
            anArray[i] = aValue
        }
    }
    return 1
}
```

Call it with an `&` in front of the array argument:

```
basicFunction(&someArray, 99)
```

Comment: what about `func basicFunction(inout anArray:[Int]`

Comment: Ha ha I forgot about that.  OK.

Comment: Can you please add to that also for others to see.  I'll mark your answer as correct.